# How should I fix my code so I return the correct output, a & instead of a question mark?

Tags: java, debugging, methods, computer-science

For this assignment we are supposed to encode URL. Ultimately, the output should be **http://www.amazon.com?id=123&author=Jim+Campbell&publisher=O%27Reilly, but I am getting  www.amazon.com?id=123?author=Jim+Campbell?publisher=O%27Reilly**

Now here's my code:

```
package MyUrl;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyUrl {
    private String mUrl;

    public MyUrl(String url) {

        if (url.contains("http://"))
            mUrl = "http://" + url;
        else
            mUrl = url;
    }

    public void addArgument(String name, String value) {
        if (mUrl.indexOf(name) == '?') {
            mUrl = mUrl + '&' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(value);
        } else {
            mUrl = mUrl + '?' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(value);
        }
    }

    public void addArgument(String name, int ivalue) {
        String newValue = Integer.toString(ivalue);

        if (mUrl.indexOf(name) == '?') {
            mUrl = mUrl + '&' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(newValue);
        } else {
            mUrl = mUrl + '?' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(newValue);
        }
    }

    public void addArgument(String name, double dvalue) {
        String newValue1 = Double.toString(dvalue);
        if (mUrl.indexOf(name) == '?') {
            mUrl = mUrl + '&' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(newValue1);
        } else {
            mUrl = mUrl + '?' + urlEncode(name) + '=' + urlEncode(newValue1);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = mUrl;

        return result;
    }

    public static String urlEncode(String text) {
        String newWord = "";
        for (int n = 0; n < text.length(); ++n) {

            char c = text.charAt(n);
            String hexValue = Integer.toHexString(c);


            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                newWord += c;
            } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                newWord += c;
            } else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                newWord += c;
            } else if (c == '_' || c == '-' || c == '.' || c == '*') {
                newWord += c;
            } else if (c == ' ') {
                newWord += '+';
            } else {
                newWord += '%' + hexValue;

            }
        }
        text = newWord;
        return text;
    }

}

    /**
     * main
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Loop, asking for a new URL to be entered.
        do {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter URL site (or 'exit')...");
            String baseUrl = sc.nextLine();
            if (baseUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                break;

            // Create a new MyUrl object and call its constructor
            MyUrl u = new MyUrl(baseUrl);
            System.out.println("Url value read was: " + baseUrl);

            // Loop, asking for argument/value input
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter URL argument name (or 'done')...");
                String argName = sc.nextLine();
                if (argName.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
                    break;
                System.out.println("Enter type of argument value (string, integer, double)...");
                String argType = sc.nextLine();

                if (argType.startsWith("s")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a string value");
                    String s = sc.nextLine();
                    u.addArgument(argName, s);
                } else if (argType.startsWith("i")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter an integer value");
                    int i = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    u.addArgument(argName, i);
                } else if (argType.startsWith("d")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a double value");
                    double d = sc.nextDouble();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    u.addArgument(argName, d);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unrecognized value type - must be (s)tring, (i)nteger, or (d)ouble");
                    continue;
                }
            } while (true);

            // Display the final url
            System.out.println("URL with appended arguments is:");
            System.out.println("  " + u.toString());

        } while (true);

        // Keep console window alive until 'enter' pressed (if needed).
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Done - press enter key to end program");
        String junk = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

And then for the output, I enter all of this, but don't get the result I want. Can someone tell me what I did incorrectly in my code?

> Enter URL site (or 'exit')... www.amazon.com
>
> Url value read was: www.amazon.com
>
> Enter URL argument name (or 'done')...
>
> id
>
> Enter type of argument value (string, integer, double)...
>
> integer
>
> Enter an integer value
>
> 123
>
> Enter URL argument name (or 'done')...
>
> author
>
> Enter type of argument value (string, integer, double)...
>
> string
>
> Enter a string value
>
> Jim Campbell
>
> Enter URL argument name (or 'done')...
>
> publisher
>
> Enter type of argument value (string, integer, double)...
>
> string
>
> Enter a string value
>
> O'Reilly
>
> Enter URL argument name (or 'done')...
>
> done
>
> URL with appended arguments is:
>   www.amazon.com?id=123?author=Jim+Campbell?publisher=O%27Reilly
>
> Enter URL site (or 'exit')...

Answer (score 2):

I noticed these.

1. In your constructor, you forgot a `!`. Replace

   ```
   if (url.contains("http://"))
   ```

   with

   ```
   if (!url.contains("http://"))
   ```
2. In all `addArgument` methods, replace

   ```
   if(mUrl.indexOf(name)=='?')
   ```

   with

   ```
   if(mUrl.indexOf('?') != -1)
   ```

**Explanation**

1. You are adding the `http://`*if it already exists there*, not the opposite. `!` is logical not, it reverses this.
2. You are trying to find the argument's name in the URL, then comparing the index (or -1) to the numeric value of `'?'`. Obviously won't work.

Comment: contains is wrong, here. You want startsWith. indexOf is slow; you're better off tracking a flag that tells you if the query string has been added. That, and make mUrl a StringBuilder.

Comment: @david not worth the trouble - you are talking about optimising to save 1 microsecond. It's the least of his problems.

Comment: The important point is that java is making an automatic widening cast of `?` from `char` to `int` (its ASCII value), which in this case is not meaningful.

Comment: Not sure you fixed it already, but there is also an issue of having a "?" when it should be a "&".

Comment: Yes. The second problem causes the condition to (almost)  never be true, so a new ? is added every time.